# Customizing JWT response from django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Tags: json, django, angular, jwt

I'm setting up Django to send a JWT Response as opposed to a view. I tried using django-rest-framework-simplejwt.

Provided in this framework, there is a function `TokenObtainPairView.as_view()` that returns a pair of jwt. I need to return the access token with another Json response as opposed to the two tokens provided.

Ideally I would like one JsonResponse that contains an access token that is the same as this one: `TokenObtainPairView.as_view()`.

I tried creating my own view which is provided below.

**UPDATE:** Provided in Settings.py

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}
```

Login URL Path

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('auth/', views.LoginView.as_view()),
]
```

LoginView I created

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data['username']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            payload = {
                'user_id': user.id,
                'exp': datetime.now(),
                'token_type': 'access'
            }

            user = {
                'user': username,
                'email': user.email,
                'time': datetime.now().time(),
                'userType': 10
            }

            token = jwt.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY).decode('utf-8')
            return JsonResponse({'success': 'true', 'token': token, 'user': user})

        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': 'false', 'msg': 'The credentials provided are invalid.'})
```

Pattern provided by framework.

```
urlpatterns = [
...
path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view()),
...
]
```

It returns this token

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNTQ5NDk3NDQ2LCJqdGkiOiI3YmU4YzkzODE4MWI0MmJlYTFjNDUyNDhkNDZmMzUxYSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOiIwIn0.xvfdrWf26g4FZL2zx3nJPi7tjU6QxPyBjq-vh1fT0Xs
>
> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoicmVmcmVzaCIsImV4cCI6MTU0OTQ5NzQ0NiwianRpIjoiOTNhYzkxMjU5NmZkNDYzYjg2OGQ0ZTM2ZjZkMmJhODciLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoiMCJ9.dOuyuFuMjkVIRI2_UcXT8_alCjlXNaiRJx8ehQDIBCg

If you go to https://jwt.io/ you will see what's returned

Answer (score 57):

- **For example**: to customize simpleJWT response by adding username and groups,

[image]

1. Override the `validate` method in `TokenObtainPairSerializer`

```py
# project/views.py

from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    def validate(self, attrs):
        data = super().validate(attrs)

        # Add your extra responses here
        data['username'] = self.user.username
        data['groups'] = self.user.groups.values_list('name', flat=True)
        return data


class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

2. replace the login view with customized view

```
# project/urls.py

from .views import MyTokenObtainPairView

urlpatterns = [
    # path('token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
]
```

> **References：** [SimpleJWT Readme](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) and the source code as below:
> [image]

Comment: Thank you! The current documentation doesn't mention overriding validate, you saved me a ton of troubleshooting.

Comment: How come the documentation isn't as clear as this answer.

Comment: in the method get_token, where ot what is the source or reference of cls and user parameters?

Comment: why this validate is not part of the documentation, this works that doesn't

Comment: I dont think you need to  set refresh and access as they are set in the parent serializer

Answer (score 12):

A very clean approach from the [django-rest-framework-simplejwt](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt) README as below

For example, I have users app where my custom User model resides. Follow serializers and views code example below.

*users/serializers.py:*

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer


class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['name'] = user.name
        # Add more custom fields from your custom user model, If you have a
        # custom user model.
        # ...

        return token
```

*users/views.py:*

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView


class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

After that, Register above View in your project's `urls.py` replacing original `TokenObtainPairView` as below.

```
from users.views import MyTokenObtainPairView

urlpatterns = [
    ..
    # Simple JWT token urls
    # path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(),
    #      name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/', CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(),
         name='token_obtain_pair')
    ..
]
```

Now get access token and decode it at [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)

Answer (score 3):

Custom Token response like this:

```py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
    
    
    class LoginView(APIView):
        permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
     
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            # ...
    
            # Get user token, include refresh and access token
            token = RefreshToken.for_user(user) 
    
            # Serializer token if it is not correct JSON format ^^
        
            return JsonResponse({'success': 'true', 'token': token, 'user': user})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue this can be resolved by something like this if you want to handle the custom response in case of an invalid credential.

```html
# JWT View
class LoginView(TokenObtainPairView):
    '''
    Returns access token and refresh token on login
    '''
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return response
        except exceptions.AuthenticationFailed:
            return Response({
            'error': True,
            'message': 'Invalid Username or Password',
        }, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```