# Django, JWT, React redirect to different page base on different group after log in

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I have 2 roles which are member and staff, and i want to redirect to the different pages depend on the users' roles using username and password e.g. after logging in as a member would redirect to member page and as a staff would redirect to onlystaff page. How I can do it. I'm using React Django JWT and Material UI.

the code:

axios.js

```
const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token')
            ? 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
            : null,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',
    }, 
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
            alert(
                'A server/network error occurred. ' +
                    'Looks like CORS might be the problem. ' +
                    'Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly.'
            );
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            originalRequest.url === baseURL + 'token/refresh/'
        ) {
            window.location.href = '/login/';
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.data.code === 'token_not_valid' &&
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized'
        ) {
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            if (refreshToken) {
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]));
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    return axiosInstance
                        .post('/token/refresh/', { refresh: refreshToken })
                        .then((response) => {
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);

                            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;
                            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;

                            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('Refresh token is expired', tokenParts.exp, now);
                    window.location.href = '/login/';
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Refresh token not available.');
                window.location.href = '/login/';
            }
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

Log-in.js

```
export default function LogIn() {
    let history = useHistory();
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        username: '',
        password: '',
    });

const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

const handleChange = (e) => {
    updateFormData({
        ...formData,
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value.trim(),
    });
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(formData);

    axiosInstance
        .post(`token/`, {
            username: formData.username,
            password: formData.password,
        })
        .then((res) => {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh);
            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token');
                history.push("/home");
            
        });
};
return (
    <Box component="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate sx={{ mt: 1, padding: 2 }}>
      <TextField
           margin="normal"
           required
           id="username"
           label="username"
           name="username"
           autoComplete="username"
           autoFocus
           onChange={handleChange}/>

      <TextField
        margin="normal"
        required
        name="password"
        label="password"
        type="password"
        id="password"
        autoComplete="current-password"
        onChange={handleChange}/>
                        
         <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                 LOG IN
          </Button>            
          </Box>    
);}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('core.urls')),
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `TokenObtainPairView.as_view()` add the `role` of the user or the `redirectPath` based on the role, into the response. Then inside your `handleSubmit` add this:

```js
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh);
            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token');


            history.push(res.data.redirectPath); // add this
```

#### Edit

You can edit the JWT itself in django, and read it from the token in the frontend, [as per this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54544978/customizing-jwt-response-from-django-rest-framework-simplejwt)

Comment: nice! I thought my answer was pretty vague. Congrats on getting to the solution - did you return the role as part of the response data or did you encode it into the JWT?

Comment: i encoded it, and it's working perfectly.